# How to make positional arguments required/disallowed depending on other positional arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want a program on the form:

```
program {a|b|c <foo>} [--config <file>]
```

Exactly one of a, b and c must be supplied, and the foo argument should be required if c is used and not allowed otherwise.

So these should be accepted calls:

```
program a
program c hello
program a --config file.conf
program b --config file.conf
program --config file.conf b
program c haha --config file.conf
```

But I would like to disallow these

```
program a haha
program b haha --config file.conf
```

Preferably, I would also like to disallow this, but that's not very important

```
program c --config file.conf hello
```

That is, disallow putting the config parameter in between.

This is my current code:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My prog')
parser.add_argument('command', type=str, choices=['a', 'b', 'c'])
parser.add_argument('foo', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--config', type=str)
```

This "works" fine, but I want the `foo` argument to be required if `command='c'` and not allowed otherwise, and I cannot find a way to do that. Right now I need to supply some dummy argument for foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `a`, `b`, and `c` subcommands rather than ordinary positional parameters. Here, rather than adding `--config` to each subparser explicitly, I defined it in a separate parser for each subparser to inherit from, using the `parents` keyword argument.

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My prog')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
config_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
config_parser.add_argument('--config')

ap = subparsers.add_parser('a', parents=[config_parser])
bp = subparsers.add_parser('b', parents=[config_parser])
cp = subparsers.add_parser('c', parents=[config_parser])
cp.add_argument("foo")

print(parser.parse_args())
```